# First order differential equation ${{dy} \over {dx}} = {( - 2x + y)^2} - 7$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing some exercise and I got to this question:

Solve ${{dy} \over {dx}} = {( - 2x + y)^2} - 7$ with $y(0) = 0$.

My approach has been to first set $u =  - 2x + y$ then I got $ - 2 = {u^2} - 7$. However, this approach leads to a wrong answer! Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$-2x+y=u $$ and so we have $y'=u'+2$ therefor, $\frac{du}{u^2-9}=dx$ or equivalently $\frac{1}{6}{(\frac{1}{u-3}-\frac{1}{u+3})}du=dx$ this shows that$$\frac{1}{6}\ln\frac{u-3}{u+3}=x+C$$

Comment: thanks,this  leads to right answer!

Comment: but i still don't know why my approach has been wrong ....

Comment: It is because you took the derivative of $u$  and treated y as constant and set that equal to rhs so that is wrong. You should get a derivative of y wrt to x in terms of u on the lhs. As this answer shows :).

Comment: Because $\frac{du}{dx}=-2+\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{dy}{du}=1+2\frac{dx}{du}$

Answer (score 0):

Once you have $\frac{du}{u^2-9}=dx$, you can also remember your hyperbolic functions, as $\frac{dtanh}{dx}(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint(for a different solution than the ones already stated);Although the linear substitution method is pretty neat and straightforward on this one, you can solve this D.E. as a Riccati's equation.
Expand; $$y'=(-2x+y)^2-7 \iff y'=y^2-4xy+4x^2-7$$
theb substitute $$y=-\frac{v'}{v}$$